# Where can I download previous / older versions of Flyway?

Tags: flyway

We are currently running version 4.0.3 and can't go to the latest as support for our database has been dropped (SQL Server 2012). I would like to get the latest version 4 release (4.2.0) - can anyone tell me if this is possible and if so, where can I find it?

Apparently the source code for all previous versions is in GitHub. Now the question becomes "Is there anywhere I can find the Windows executable version of Flyway 4.2.0?"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The various binaries, as well as the source, for 4.2.0 can be downloaded from [Maven Central](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/flywaydb/flyway-commandline/4.2.0/).

Here is the [4.2.0 Windows zip](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/flywaydb/flyway-commandline/4.2.0/flyway-commandline-4.2.0-windows-x64.zip).

Answer (score 2):

You will probably have to build the executable from source using one of the releases on their Github. 4.2.0 is available [here](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/releases/tag/flyway-4.2.0)